# Android TextClock misbehaving

Tags: android, android-view

I set two TextClock views in my activity, one using `format24hours:"dd/MM/yyyy"`, the other `format24hours:"HH:mm:ss"`.

I tested it on my phone (Motorola G6 with Android O) the correct format is displayed.
Now i'm working on a tablet (Galaxy Tab E with Android Nougat -> Lineage ROM) and the format displayed for both views is `"hh:mm aa"`.

I tried forcing the format programmatically in addiction to the xml, but it is just ignored.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I forced the 12 hours format.
I wanted the app to display `MMMM dd, yyyy | HH:mm:ss`,
so I coded

```
tvTimeStamp.format12Hour = "MMMM dd, yyyy | HH:mm:ss"
tvTimeStamp.format24Hour = "MMMM dd, yyyy | HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: I somehow cant see the difference between those two

Answer (score -1):

Just use SingleDateFormat to show all formatted dates and times in correct for you format. You can find example in http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: you should format your Date to correct presentation, shouldn't you?

Comment: Actually I shouldn't. The app is gonna be only released in a country where the date format is the one I'm using. Still using a correct format doesn't fix the problem with the TextClock.